# Passing an instance of an object as argument in it's own method?

Tags: java

I am trying to pass an instance of an object as itself as a method parameter, but I am not sure how you pass the "whole" object, as there to my knowledge isn't a instance variable holding a reference to the object

Comment: What is  the question ?

Comment: You do not need to pass a reference to the object itself to its own methods - this is always done implicitly through `this`

Answer (score 7):

Call `this`, it's always available implicitly, provided that the method is not `static`.

Answer (score 4):

You can't pass objects, only references to objects. To get the default object use `this` like

```
public void method() {
    anotherMethod(this);
}
```